# returning mysql results to into php string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print a string out to html when doing a MySQL query. It seems to work and when it echos it out it gives me error. The code is :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM vehicle_type ORDER BY cat_id desc');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$category = $row['category'];
$count++;



$vehicle_types .= "<a href='#' onclick='document.getElementById('vehicle_types').value='$count';$('#exec').show();$('#coach').hide();$('#minibus').hide();$('#limos').hide();vehicle_type_name.innerHTML = 'Vehicle type selected : Executive vehicle';vehicle_selected.innerHTML = ''; ' class='btn new btn-primary'>$category</a>";

}
```

when I echo out the result it gives me :

```
 <a href='#' onclick='document.getElementById('vehicle_types').value='1';$('#exec').show();$('#coach').hide();$('#minibus').hide();$('#limos').hide();vehicle_type_name.innerHTML = 'Vehicle type selected : Executive vehicle';vehicle_selected.innerHTML = ''; ' class='btn new btn-primary'>Minibus</a>
```

When it should give me :

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('vehicle_type').value='1';$('#exec').show();$('#coach').hide();$('#minibus').hide();$('#limos').hide();vehicle_type_name.innerHTML = 'Vehicle type selected : Executive vehicle';vehicle_selected.innerHTML = ''; " class="btn new btn-primary">Executive cars</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's because you're chaining single-quotes, the `onclick()` outer quotes should be double, not single.

Comment: yes put cannot make a string and echo out double quotes?

Comment: Sure you can, you just need to escape it `onclick=\"...`

Comment: Since you're using jQuery or something like it: `$('#vehicle_type').val(1)` is much less verbose. You could also minimize how much junk you need to stuff into that tag by using `$('...').click()` to set a handler method that way.

Comment: Thanks, I did try /" !!!! Works a treat

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving all those onClick statements to a function for better readability.

Also, be consistent with your use of jQuery.

```
$vehicle_types .= '<a href="#" onclick="vehicleType_onClick(\'' . $count . '\')" 
                   class="btn new btn-primary">' . $category . '</a>';

<script>
function vehicleType_onClick(count){
    $('#vehicle_types').val(count);

    $('#exec').show();
    $('#coach').hide();
    $('#minibus').hide();
    $('#limos').hide();
    $('input[name=vehicle_type_name']).html('Vehicle type selected : Executive vehicle');
    $('input[name=vehicle_selected']).html(''); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: I was getting to that next!!! I want to loop through the results and then have the show/hide change accordingly. Any ideas? Will put code up when tried it

Comment: Pass in some type of ID to the function. `if(type == 'limos') { $('#limos').show(); }`.

Comment: yes, but that's assuming I know the types! What if there are 7 different ones, I will have to loop through and make set when doing that wont I, that's where I'm going to get stuck

Comment: You have the types from the database. You will just need to make sure the Javascript and DB values align.